# Does S3 provide any bucket policy to share the objects to IAM user for a limited time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to share my bucket (sourcebucket) with an IAM User (testuser) for a limited time window. Does AWS provide any bucket policy so that I can share my bucket objects with the IAM User for a limited time frame?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:user/testuser"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://advancedweb.hu/how-s3-signed-urls-work/ - this should help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does AWS provide any bucket policy so that I can share my bucket objects with the IAM User for a limited time frame?

Yes.

Check the `DateGreaterThan` and `DateLessThan` conditions and the `aws:CurrentTime` condition key. Here's an example, using the policy in your question as a base:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:user/testuser"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "DateGreaterThan": {"aws:CurrentTime": "2020-04-01T00:00:00Z"},
            "DateLessThan": {"aws:CurrentTime": "2020-06-30T23:59:59Z"}
        }
    }
]
}
```

Here are some useful links:

- [AWS Global Condition Context Keys: `aws:CurrentTime`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-currenttime)
- [AWS: Allows Access Within Specific Dates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws-dates.html)